# How to know the exact disk space used by cassandra to store data pushed to a table?

Tags: cassandra

I want to do few tests related to diskspace used by cassandra after every write operation. I am pushing huge data during my tests.
I have one keyspace and a table created in cassandra. I want to know the diskspace used by cassandra for data which I pushed in a table.

I noticed that, when I insert some data, it doesn't reflect immediately into data directory inside cassandra installation directory. So I tried to stop cassandra and restart it. As a result, I could see some files/directory created inside keyspace/data folder.

But the amount of data which I pushed to cassandra should be in MBs as it's huge. But size of data directory is in KBs while size of commit log is 32,768 kB. So, I am not sure if data is force flushed from commit table to SS table or not after restarting cassandra.

As I am new to cassandra, I am struggling to get the exact diskspace used by cassandra. Do I need to follow other steps? Or cassandra internally compresses data to a huge extent?

Answer (score 2):

> I have one keyspace and a table created in cassandra. I want to know the disk space used by cassandra for data which I pushed in a table.

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this, would be to use `du`.

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1 data
2.4M    data/system
500K    data/system_schema
0       data/system_traces
0       data/system_distributed
448K    data/system_auth
36G     data/dev
36G.    data
```

If you set `max-depth=2` or specify a specific keyspace directory, you can see the actual on-disk usage by table, as well.

> I am not sure if data is force flushed from commit table to SS table or not after restarting cassandra.

Yes, it absolutely is.  Data written immediately will be reflected in the commitlog (on disk), but will not be written to a SSTable until the memtables are flushed.  A restart forces this process, because any remaining commitlogs are verified at restart.

> Or cassandra internally compresses data to a huge extent?

Assuming you mostly accepted the defaults, checking your table definitions should reveal this line:

```
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64',
 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
```

Also relative to prior versions, the Cassandra 3 storage engine is very efficient in its use of disk space.

Comment: But, data will be pushed in Data directory inside keyspace only when memtable is full right? And I noticed that, when I write data stop cassandra and restart cassandra, some data is missing in query result. Does it mean data is not flushed properly from memtable to SSTable (Disk)?

Comment: @Madhusudan Is there a chance that you have set durable writes to `false` in your keyspace definition?  This is also why you shouldn't just restart Cassandra.  There is an accepted practice of running `nodetool disablegossip` and `nodetool drain` before killing the PID.

Comment: I tried "nodetool flush" to flush data from MemTable to SSTable and it worked. I tried your suggested commands as well...seems useful. And yes due to compress algorithm, data is getting compressed while it is written to SSTable